# Why frameGrabber.start() Not Grabbing the Frames From Video File

Tags: java, ffmpeg, javacv

Here the Below code  in JAVA

public class Read{

```
public static void main(String []args) throws IOException, Exception, InterruptedException, ExecutionException
{
```

//    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ffmpeg -r 1 -i sample%d.png -s 320x240 -aspect 4:3 CHANDIGARH.mp4");
        FFmpegFrameGrabber frameGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber("C:/Users/Danish/Music/CHANDIGARH.mp4");
        frameGrabber.setFrameNumber(0);
        frameGrabber.start();

```
    IplImage i;



    try {
        for(int ii=0;ii<=frameGrabber.getLengthInFrames();ii++){

            OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage converter = new OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage();      

              Java2DFrameConverter paintConverter = new Java2DFrameConverter();
             i = converter.convert(frameGrabber.grab());


            Frame frame = converter.convert(i);
            BufferedImage img=paintConverter.getBufferedImage(frame,1);
            IplImage iplImage = converter.convert(paintConverter.convert(img));

        String path = "F:\\"+ii+".png";
        ImageIO.write(img,"png", new File(path));

        }
        frameGrabber.stop();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

}

Comment: It will be good to use OpenCV which has a good Java wrapper.

Comment: yes i tried with OpenCV but didn't find any thing which help me to solve that!

Comment: How did you tried the OpenCV (show the code), you can go to http://opencv.org and download  the package, and then you can find a jar file for Java, and then you use it, very easy and powerful.